# Template strings ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As per screenshot on the right I have JSON object  playerStats.name ....gives me "goals", "losses" etc.

I wanted to render to the screen only selected ones hence statsToDisplay array and finally instead of displaying that ugly i.e. goal_assist I wanted to display Assists (see const el=... line in comments).

To replace {playerStats.name} I thought I use string interpolation like this

```
el["`${playerStats.name}`"]
```

I cannot get it to work, is it doable like this at all?

[image]

Comment: Lose the outer quotes, template strings just use the backticks.

Comment: el['\`${playerStats.name}\`']

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara thanks but it doesn't work ;(

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I know backticks will resolve to goals_assist ==> el['goal_assist'] and then I should end up with Assists which I want to render (see const el = .... line in comments)

Answer (score 1):

It should simply be normal bracket notation:

```javascript
el[playerStats.name]
```

Comment: Nope, still do not work, I even try ugly el[' " ' + playerStats.name + ' " '] and it doesn work either

Comment: What is `playerStats.name`? If it's a string like `goals` then see my answer.

Comment: playerStats is a JSON returned by React app and it matches the .stats {} portion of that JSON as per screenshot on the right, so playerStats.name is "goals", "losses" etc. .........maybe I need to stringify it?

Comment: @maciejk77 There are no quotes in the property names! Get rid of them! If you use them in your object literal, they're just delimiters like in a string literal, not actually part of the name.

Answer (score 0):

The line you mentioned:

```
el["`${playerStats.name}`"]
```

should be:

```
el[`${playerStats.name}`]
```

But I can't see this in the context of the screenshot.

Comment: return (<div key={playerStats.name}>el[\`${playerStats.name}\`] ...and doesn't work either

Comment: BINGO!! got it {el[playerStats.name]}  Thank you all for help!